Wish to draw 7 red edges going out from $x$
Below is my code and its output.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw regular octagon
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum size=6cm] (octagon) at (0,0) {};
    
    % Draw center node
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2mm, fill=white] (x) at (0,0) {$x$};
  
    % Draw corner nodes
    \foreach \i/\name in {2/v_1, 1/v_2, 8/v_3, 7/v_4, 6/v_5, 5/v_{l-2}, 4/v_{l-1}, 3/v_l} {
        \node[draw, circle, minimum size=10mm, fill=white] (\name) at (octagon.corner \i) {$\name$};
    }

    % Connect corner nodes in sequence as a path
    \draw (v_5) -- (v_4) -- (v_3) -- (v_2) -- (v_1)--(v_l)--(v_{l-1})--(v_{l-2});
    \draw[dashed] (v_5) -- (v_{l-2});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I hope to have 7 red edges drawn as shown in the figure, but I’m not sure if there’s a approach.


What is the prolem? Finding the end points of these paths or do you want them to you actually want them to change their width along their length?

@Qrrbrbirlbel Initially, I wanted to add these red lines without knowing their exact angles. Thanks to NonnoDino's answer, I now get them

You can easily draw the 7 red edges going out from the central node $x$ by using a foreach loop to generate the angles for the arrows. The angles in degrees for 7 equally spaced edges are -45°, 0°, 45°, 90°, 135°, 180°, and 225°. The following code will add those red edges while keeping the rest of your drawing intact.
Here’s the updated code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta} % using arrows.meta library
                                              % for nicer arrows
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw regular octagon
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8, minimum size=6cm] (octagon) at (0,0) {};  

    % Draw corner nodes
    \foreach \i/\name in {2/v_1, 1/v_2, 8/v_3, 7/v_4, 6/v_5, 5/v_{l-2}, 4/v_{l-1}, 3/v_l} {
        \node[draw, circle, minimum size=10mm, fill=white] (\name) at (octagon.corner \i) {$\name$};
    }

    % Connect corner nodes in sequence as a path
    \draw (v_5) -- (v_4) -- (v_3) -- (v_2) -- (v_1)--(v_l)--(v_{l-1})--(v_{l-2});
    \draw[dashed] (v_5) -- (v_{l-2});

    % Draw 7 red edges from the center node x
    \foreach \x in {-45,0,45,...,225}{
    \draw[>-stealth, red, line width=0.4mm] (0,0) -- (\x:3.5);
    }

    % Draw center node
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2mm, fill=white] (x) at (0,0) {$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


